# Angular 1.5.6, $postLink and typescript

Tags: angularjs, hook, typescript1.8

I am trying to use $postLink in my directive (using typescript and ng 1.5.6) Unfortunately, I really do not understand where to use this.
Should it be a public function named "$postLink" within the body of the directive's class ?

The following is not working:

```
public $postLink(scope: ng.IScope , element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes):void {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I got it to work using typescript (this seed, precisely: https://github.com/b091/ts-skeleton) :

```
import {directive} from "../../../decorators/directive";

@directive()
export class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    public restrict: string = "A";

    public link: ng.IDirectivePrePost = {
        pre: ($scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes): void => {
            console.log("pre() being called");
        },
        post: ($scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes): void => {
            console.log("post() being called");
        }
    }
}
```

You can see in the typings file for angular, that IDirective can take either:

```
interface IDirectivePrePost {
    pre?: IDirectiveLinkFn;
    post?: IDirectiveLinkFn;
}
```

OR

```
interface IDirectiveLinkFn {
    (
        scope: IScope,
        instanceElement: IAugmentedJQuery,
        instanceAttributes: IAttributes,
        controller: {},
        transclude: ITranscludeFunction
    ): void
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this in your component's controller:

```
class MyCtrl {
  static $inject = ['$element'];
  // If you need the element for DOM manipulation,
  // then inject it as $element.
  // $scope can also be injected.
  constructor($element:ng.IAugmentedJQuery) {}

  // $postLink is different from a directive's link and doesn't have
  // arguments.
  public $postLink() {
     // The attrs can't be injected but instead you can define the
     // bindings of the component.
  }
}
```

Comment: One of the first thing I tried, unfortunately nothing is fired and I cannot find out why.

Comment: Is it an angular.directive or an angular.component?

Comment: this is a directive

Comment: It should work with both component and directive. Can you post the directive definition object maybe something is different there?